# Expected number of updates to find approximate minimum using the following algo

Tags: algorithm, probability, min

Consider the following code:

```
public int find_exponent(array) {
    int count = 0;
    double min = epsilon;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] < min) {
        count++;
        min = min/2;
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Suppose the input array is of length n and randomly generated(and the entries are iid and ranges [0, 1]) from some unknown density f. What will be Expected Value of count ? I understand as the underlying density is unknown it's not possible to get an explicit solution but what I want is a solution in terms of f (or the corresponding CDF: F) and the initial guess for min i.e epsilon.

**Note:** I'm not interested to find the exact minimum in the given array

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. Don't expect finished answers here, rather tell us what you have done and where you have a question or a problem. Also, the question *may* be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I get that this is pseudo  code etc. but `int min  = epsilon`? at least use `double` or `float` or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this problem the following way.

First off, I suppose that the type of `min` is meant to be `float/double` since your array `array` has values in the range `[0, 1]`. Now, define `F` as

```
F(x) = P(X <= x)
```

i.e the cumulative density function and `G(i, c)` to be the probability that after the `i-th` iteration we have that `count == c`

You can see that:

```
G(x, c) = P(X >= eps/2^c)*G(x, c) + P(X <= eps/2^(c-1))*G(x, c-1) =
(1-F(eps/2^c))*G(x, c) + F(eps/2^(c-1))*G(x, c-1)
```

Notice that since `G(0, 0)=1` we can calculate `G(x, c), for 0<=x<=n, 0<=c<=n` with a bottom-up approach.

Here are the first couple of values of `G`:

```
G(0, 0) = 1

G(1, 0) = 1-F(e)
G(1, 1) = F(e)

G(2, 0) = (1-F(e))^2
G(2, 1) = F(e)(1-F(e)) + F(e)(1-F(e/2))
G(2, 2) = F(e)F(e/2)
```

The expected `count` would be:

```
E[count] = 0*G(n,0)+1*G(n,1)+...+n*G(n,n)
```

Comment: Thanks @svs !! In my approach I was mistakenly treating the probability term ( your G(x,y)) as the expectation and ran into ocean of confusion....thanks a lot!!!